# END-PERFORM needed, but also not needed?

Tags: formatting, cobol, fizzbuzz, gnucobol

[COBOL code with terminal errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNfDb.png)

The error messages are:

```
fizzbuzz.cob:12: error: PERFORM statement not terminated by END-PERFORM
fizzbuzz.cob:18: error: syntax error, unexpected END-PERFORM
```

I'm getting a compile error with this program because it says that the `PERFORM` statement needs an `END-PERFORM`, but it also says that the `END-PERFORM` is unexpected. I'm confused as to why it doesn't seem to compile, what is the error here?

```
000100 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
000110 AUTHOR. AMBER.
000200 PROGRAM-ID. FIZZBUZZ.
000300 ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
000400 DATA DIVISION.
000500 FILE SECTION.
000600 WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
000700 01 WS-I PIC 99 VALUE 1.
000800 01 WS-R PIC 99.
000810 01 WS-NO PIC 99.
000900 PROCEDURE DIVISION.
001000         PERFORM UNTIL WS-I = 99
001100         DIVIDE WS-I BY 3 GIVING WS-NO REMAINDER WS-R
001200             IF WS-R = 0 DISPLAY "FIZZ"
001210             ELSE DISPLAY WS-I
001220             END-IF
001230         ADD 1 TO WS-I IF WS-I < 99
001240 END-PERFORM.
001300 STOP RUN.
001400 END PROGRAM FIZZBUZZ.
```

The intention is to have the program do the first half of a `FIZZBUZZ` program, just replacing all the numbers divisible by 3 with the string "FIZZ".

I am using GnuCOBOL to compile. The system is running on Pop_os! Linux

I tried placing a full stop/period at several points in the program, actually, the first compile error comes from having a full stop at the end of line 16. I suspect it's a formatting error.

Comment: The problem is the incomplete `IF` statement. `IF WS-I < 99` requires an imperative statement -- some action to do, if true. For now, remove that code. It should run displaying `FIZZ` for every three numbers. Then add the code for displaying `BUZZ`.

Comment: Thank you, I reversed the order of line 17, the part containing "IF WS-I..." so that it begins with the "IF" instead of hte "ADD", adding an "END-IF to the next line completed it and made the program run! thanks again for hte help!

Comment: Please only provide images _additional_ to the question for helping to show the point. The actual error message you see is missing in the question, edit that in.

Comment: @RickSmith Do you mind creating an answer out of this? The point is correct - as is the "dangling IF" consumes the `END-PERFORM`, which is then missing for the `PERFORM`.

Comment: Just a note: a compiler that abides to fixed-form reference-format rules (and you normally wouldn't use sequence numbers otherwise) will error with this code as statements need to start in Area B (columns 12+). 
For example `cobc -std=cobol85` (GC 3.2+): "fizzbuzz.cob:18: error: END-PERFORM should not start in Area A  fizzbuzz.cob:19: error: start of statement in Area A"

Comment: @SimonSobisch - *Do you mind creating an answer out of this?* I can't explain why `cobc` says `PERFORM statement not terminated by END-PERFORM` or `syntax error, unexpected END-PERFORM`. My Micro Focus compiler won't compile the original code, because the `AUTHOR` paragraph is before the `PROGRAM-ID` paragraph. After correcting for that, the program runs fine, despite the incomplete `IF` statement. With `ans85 flag"ans85"`, it shows 5 errors. The errors shown are different than what `cobc` generates. The best I could have done is a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would expect the compiler to point to this line and flag it as an error, it did not. However, this is the line causing the compilation error, despite the message:

```
001230         ADD 1 TO WS-I IF WS-I < 99
```

"IF WS-I < 99" followed by END-PERFORM represent an incomplete IF statement.

Comment: Thanks to this question GC 3.2 will do so:

badcode.cob:18: error: syntax error, unexpected END-PERFORM
badcode.cob:17: error: IF without imperative statement
badcode.cob:12: error: PERFORM statement not terminated by END-PERFORM